In databricks-sdk how can you create a cluster, controlling the number of init script retries explicitly?
So far, looking through the clusters docs, seeing there is a  blocking create_and_wait and the non-blocking create call. And the default behavior of the create appears to be, an init script will be retried for 20 minutes .
I am wondering if anyone has figured out how to lock it down to say retries=0 or retries=1 . Or is the only way to do this, to use the create_and_wait(..., timeout=x) where you choose a timeout that ends up cutting down the retry count?

